# Steklov averages and negative parabolic sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde

Suppose one is given a function 
$$
w \in L^p(0,T;W^{1,p}(\Omega)) \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{dw}{dt} \in L^{p'}(0,T; W^{-1,p'}(\Omega))
$$
I am interested if the following holds:

Denote the Steklov average to be $[f]_h(x,t) := \frac{1}{2h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h} f(x,s)\ ds$, then does the following hold:
$$
\int_a^b \left< \frac{d[w]_h}{dt}, \varphi \right>_{(W^{-1,p'}(\Omega),W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)}(t) \ dt = \int_a^b \left[ \left<\frac{dw}{dt}, \varphi \right>_{(W^{-1,p'}(\Omega),W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)} \right]_h(t) \ dt
$$

Edit: My question was not framed correctly. I ask what class of functions allow for such an equality? Smooth functions are admissible for $w$, how much can I relax the condition further? Here $\varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ only as a function of $x$.

Edit: The interval $(a,b) \subset (0+h,T-h)$ for any fixed small $h$.

Comment: How is the Steklov average defined close to the boundary of the time interval? Is there an extension?

Comment: I have added an edit which should clarify my question a little more now.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be if the Steklov average commutes with $\langle \cdot, \phi \rangle$ and the derivative by t. Then you could pull the Steklov average inside and the two sides are equal. I dont see any reason why this shoulden hold for all functions where everything is defined, i.e. for all functions in your domain.

Comment: It is true for functions and false if $\frac{dw}{dt}$ is any generic distribution. So my question is how much can one relax the condition of $\frac{dw}{dt}$ being a function?